# How to render event in custom built calendar

Tags: javascript, html, angular, sass

I have created a custom calendar view for one of my projects using angular. I tried to use a full calendar library but it doesn't give many customization options. This is my custom view in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehmzsw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss). I want to render events. but I don't understand how to do that.

my expectation is this 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's only a idea. You has events like

```
events:any[]=[{
    startDate:'2020-01-06',
    endDate:'2020-01-08',
    event:'Hello word'
  }]
```

When you render the calendar add "data attributes" and put a template variable reference to allow us to get it using ViewChildren -get the "row" because will be important when a event call in two differents weeks. It's interesting you give as data-day attribute the day you show. For this create a function like

```
getDate(day:any,row:number)
  {
    if (day.isSameMonth)
      return this.currentMonth.getFullYear()+'-'+('0'+(this.currentMonth.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)
              +'-'+('0'+day.day).slice(-2)
    if (row==0)
    {
      return this.currentMonth.getMonth()?
         this.currentMonth.getFullYear()+'-'+
         ('0'+this.currentMonth.getMonth()).slice(-2)+'-'+
         ('0'+day.day).slice(-2):
         (this.currentMonth.getFullYear()-1)+'-12-'+('0'+day.day).slice(-2)
    }
      return this.currentMonth.getMonth()!=11?
         this.currentMonth.getFullYear()+'-'+
         ('0'+this.currentMonth.getMonth()+2).slice(-2)+'-'+
         ('0'+day.day).slice(-2):
         (this.currentMonth.getFullYear()+1)+'-01-'+('0'+day.day).slice(-2)

  }

<div #daysCell 
  [attr.data-day]="getDate(days,i)"
  [attr.data-row]="i"
  [ngClass] = "{'today-cell':days.isToday === true}">
    {{days.day}}
</div>
```

Render the events in a div as

```
<div *ngFor="let evento of events;let i=index">
  <div #event [attr.data-event]="i" class="event">{{evento.event}}</div>
</div>
```

Well, the funny part. We get the "cells" and the "events" as

```
  @ViewChildren('daysCell') cells:QueryList<ElementRef>
  @ViewChildren('event') eventsCells:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

And in a function renderEvent you use Renderer2 to give position left top-rigth to your elements

```
renderEvents(){
    const cells=this.cells.map(x=>{
      return {
        pos:x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect(),
        day:x.nativeElement.getAttribute('data-day'),
        row:x.nativeElement.getAttribute('data-row'),
      }

    })
    this.eventsCells.forEach((x:any,index:number)=>{
      const cellStart=cells.find(c=>c.day==this.events[index].startDate)
      const cellEnd=cells.find(c=>c.day==this.events[index].endDate)
      this.render.setStyle(x.nativeElement,'top',(cellStart.pos.top+1)+'px')
      this.render.setStyle(x.nativeElement,'left',(cellStart.pos.left+1)+'px')
      this.render.setStyle(x.nativeElement,'width',
          (cellEnd.pos.left-cellStart.pos.left+cellEnd.pos.width)+'px')
    })
  }
```

Well, it's only an aprox. You need check if the event are in two weeks, if a event it's showed or not... and another ajusts (I hope minnor adjusts)

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kczk6e?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Update** if we want to place more than one event in a date, we need add a propertie to the "events", e.g. we can called "row", so, the "top" becomes like

```
this.render.setStyle(
      x.nativeElement,
      "top",
      (this.events[index].row
        ? this.events[index].row *
            (2 + x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height) +
          cellStart.pos.top
        : cellStart.pos.top + 1) + "px"
    );
```

Now, the dificult is know how give the value to "row". For this, we need loop over the events, store in an array the days that are ocupped and, if one is ocuped increment the row. puff. make a function

```
getEventsRows() {
    const datesOcupped: any[] = [];
    this.events.forEach(x => {
      x.row = 0;
      const startDate = new Date(x.startDate).getTime();
      const endDate = new Date(x.endDate).getTime();

      for (let date = startDate;date <= endDate;date = date + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
        const dateOcupped = datesOcupped.length? 
              datesOcupped.find(x => x.time == date): null;
        if (!dateOcupped) {
          datesOcupped.push({
            time: date,
            row: 0
          });
        } else dateOcupped.row++;

        x.row = dateOcupped? dateOcupped.row > x.row?
                             dateOcupped.row: x.row: 0;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have one question if I have another event on the same day it will replace my old event. how can I fix that? Your opinion highly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: I just put out an idea in the updated answer: The "events" must have a propertie, call it, e.g. "row", so we need change the "top" according this "row". Well, to calculate the "row" we store in an array the "dates ocupped" with each event. NOTE: Take account when the cells are not enough height